# Data copy from one DB to other

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql DBs, one is testing & other is production(which are on two different servers), i want to move few users from testing to production.

There are few tables which are related via primary & foreign keys(so duplicate entries should be not stored).

What will be the best way to implement this? Any query samples?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Keep the testing & production servers in sync perhaps?

Comment: For ex,there 1000 prod.users & 200 test users, i want to move these 200 users data to prod.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set up some tables using the federated engine so you can simply copy the data across, carrying out any checks you require to prevent duplicates.

First check if you have the federated engine available, in the MySQL shell do 'show engines', hopefully you will have a line like this:
`FEDERATED  | YES | Federated MySQL storage engine| NO | NO | NO ||`

If not, try putting the word 'federated' by itself on a line in your my.cnf file (which is generally in /etc), then stopping & restarting the mysqld service.

If the daemon does not restart then your installation does not have the federated plugin, take out the line from my.cnf to enable a restart. If that is the case then you'll have to download, install and enable the plugin.

Once you have the engine available you can set up tables like this:

`create table tb1 (col1 varchar(10)) ENGINE=FEDERATED CONNECTION='mysql://mysqlusername:password@192.168.1.1:3306/databasename/tablename';`

Where the columns in the federated (local) table are the same as the columns in the remote table to which you are connecting.

After you have run the 'create table' command, run 'show create table ...' and ensure that the federated engine really is being used because MySQL will use a MyISAM engine without issuing a message if there is an error in the config.

Ensure that you have set up permissions on the db to allow for logins from the remote system.

That's about it, once the federated table is set up it can be read & written to as if it was local (but don't forget that if you are linking to your production db then you are working with real data!).

Comment: I have not used federated engine, do you have some example?